# How to check if a specific string exist in a column in SQL? (eg: need to find 'ice' only but not 'service')

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to categorized the comment with keyword in SQL Server but I don't know how to get a specific string.

The word I need is ice only, but with the code '%ice%' I will get 'notice', 'service'...

```
SELECT 
    comment, 
    (CASE WHEN comment LIKE '%ice%' THEN 'Ice' END) AS comment_category
FROM events
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If `comment` consists of words separated by spaces, you can do:

```
' ' + comment + ' ' like '% ice %'
```

You can even add other delimiters, such as:

```
' ' + comment + ' ' like '%[- ,.()]ice[- ,.()]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use SQL Server's kinda sorta regex:

```
'.' + comment + '.' like '%[^a-z0-9]ice[^a-z0-9]%'
```